# Sending byte array in spring cloud Message with spring cloud stream, kafka binder

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

Now I am using org.springframework.messaging.Message to send a message and I need to add some text info and a byte array there.

```
@Bean public Function<Message<HashMap<String, Object>>, Message<HashMap<String, Object>>> handleCreateImageRequest() {
return comments -> {
    final byte[] byteImage = ...
    final HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("file", byteImage);
    result.put("youtubeUrl", extractedComments.get("youtubeUrl"));
    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(result).build();
};}
```

With current configuration I receive error on the consumer side:

Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot parse payload ; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of java.util.Objects (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABLAAAASwCAYAAADrIbPPAACAAE..........

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: handleCreateImageRequest
    stream:
      bindings:
        handleCreateImageRequest-in-0:
          destination: createImageQueue
          content-type: application/json
        handleCreateImageRequest-out-0:
          destination: readyImageQueue
          content-type: application/json
      kafka:
        binder:
          zkNodes: kafka
          brokers: kafka
```

What is the best way to pass byte array with kafka? Is it possible that way?

Comment: Possible solution: set content-type: application/x-java-object, change Message<HashMap<String, Object>> to Message<byte[]>, all additional info add into header.